# Xamarin.iOS - MSBUILD doesn't generate IPA

Tags: ios, visual-studio, msbuild, xamarin.ios

I am setting up build environment for ios app. I am using iMac as build host with Visual Studio 2013 community.
When I build solution from visual studio everything works fine and it generates IPA. But when I try to do it from msbuild project builds fine but it doesn't generate IPA. however it gives me this warning:

> (_SayHello target) ->
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Windows.After.targets(
>   54,5): warning : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Command line I am using: `msbuild "solution.sln" /t:build /p:Configuration=release`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer for this in [here](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/64295/msbuild-doesnt-generate-ipa)

it requires two more attributes in command line 1) ServerAddress and 2) ServerUsernameExample

```
msbuild "solution.sln" /t:build /p:Configuration=release /p:ServerAddress=xx.xx.xx.xx:22 /p:ServerUser=userName
```

where xx.xx.xx.xx is the ip address of the Mac build host,
and "userName" is a valid username on the Mac Build Host.

Comment: '/p:ServerAddress=macName /p:ServerUser=macUser' worked for me. Our mac is a member of windows domain.

Answer (score 0):

We had been using the mdtool and vstool. [See also this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38847562/build-xamarin-mac-project-from-terminal/54093612#54093612). The msbuild command is recommended and supported. This msbuild command on the Mac itself creates the app:

```
msbuild -target:Build "my.sln" -property:Configuration="Release" -property:Platform="iPhone"
```

We then take the app file created

```
 cd myapp/bin/iPhone/Release
 mkdir Payload
 cp -R my.app Payload
```

then zip the payload as the IPA file

```
 /usr/bin/zip -ry my.ipa "Payload"
```